# Trouble with non-capturing groups in regular expression

Tags: regex

I'm attempting to capture the 6 digit number in the following:

```
ObjectID: !nrtdms:0:!session:slonwswtest1:!database:TEST:!folder:ordinary,486150:
```

I tried the following regex:

```
\d+(?::$)
```

attempting to use a non-capturing group to strip the colon out of the returned match, but it returns the colon as in:

```
486150:
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe `\d{6}` would be simpler than asserting that it's in the last part of the string…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a positive lookahead:

```
\d+(?=:$)
```

A *non-capturing group* is simply a group that cannot be accessed via a backreference; they still are part of the match, nonetheless.

Alternatively, you can use

```
(\d+):$
```

and obtain the 1st match group.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your regex tool is returning the complete match since you don't have any capture group there. Try to enclose the `\d+` in a capture group, and find the way to get capture group 1 in your regex tool.

Alternatively, you can also use positive *look-ahead*:

```
\d+(?=:$)
```

And given that you want to capture 6 digits, you can make that explicit:

```
\d{6}
```

Comment: You're probably right about the tool. The look-ahead approach is great though. Thanks a lot.

Comment: He doesn't have any capture groups in that regex, though.

Comment: @arshajii. o.O. Didn't notice that.

Comment: I was misunderstanding the purpose of non-capturing groups, and groups in general, it seems. A positive look-ahead is what I needed to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a positive lookahead rather than a non-capturing group

```
\d+(?=:$)
```

Answer (score 2):

Non-capturing [groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) are groups that will not create a capture (to be used in backreferences or extracted from the match result). Nonetheless they will *match* the expression.

What you're looking for is [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) - to test the expression but exclude it from the match:

```
\d+(?=:$)
```